# Why does image url need to have request.scheme?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

We are getting this error in our pages. We can do a simple check and implement the request.scheme(which we are in the process of implementing) but w3.org states that resources can have relative schemes. Isn't og:image is similar to an image tag and should support all the features of an image tag.

Error:

```
Object at URL 'http://www.slideshare.net/jessedee/100-bullet-points-from-cannes-lions-2012' of type 'slideshare:presentation' is invalid because the given value '//cdn.slidesharecdn.com/100bulletpointsfromcanneslions12-120626070638-phpapp02-thumbnail-2?1340766735' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value for Facebook's `og:image` meta tag can't be protocol relative, it must be absolute

Comment: is there a reason for not supporting scheme relative urls?

Comment: No idea, it may be arbitrary, in many cases http://something.com and https://something.com are not the same resources, so assuming protocol relative will always work isn't necessarily safe. Also, facebook will cache the http version of the image and render that itself to HTTPS users